# Get plain text from html string

Tags: strip-tags

I am creating a xml file which will pull the description of the product (opencart). The problem is that it displays all the html inside the description. I want to get the plain text without any html tags, divs, styles etc.

For example the sting outputs the below html at the xml

```html
<p><span style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 18px; font-style: italic;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna.</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip.</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">&nbsp;nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip.</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">&nbsp;</span></p>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></p>

<ul>
 <li><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></li>
</ul>

<p><em><strong><span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip</span></strong></em></p>

<p><span style="font-family: Arial;">&nbsp;</span></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

at 
$product['description'] and I want to keep only the description without the html tags.

I tried

> $proddescr= strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

but it gives me errors at the xml

I also tried

> $proddescr = strip_tags($product['description'];
>   ehco $proddescr;

but also no luck

Can you please tell me a method to keep only the text of the string?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<![CDATA['.strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($product['description'])).']]
```